# How do you transfer a domain hosted on WordPress to Media Temple?

Tags: domains, wordpress, mediatemple

WordPress offers this service for $120, but I think that's too much. Is there an easy way to do this besides paying the wordpress guys a bunch of money? I'm just not sure of of all the steps i need to do in order to get my domain moved. This includes moving the domain as well as export and moving my content.

Also I'm transfering to Media Template because I want to host other sites as well and I want them in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this in the following manner:

1. Download an export file from your Wordpress.com blog. Make sure to tick the option about downloading attachments as well.
2. "Move" your domain to Media Temple. The question here is where you bought your domain. If on Wordpress.com, then I have no idea if they offer a way to change DNS settings but they should. If not, you will surely have access to some sort an admin tool to do it. What you need to do is to change DNS servers to Media Temple's (ns1.mediatemple.net and ns2.mediatemple.net). Then you need to log in to your Media Temple account and "add" this domain so that its zone file is created and tied with your MT hosting.
3. Install Worpdress on Media Temple under your domain. You can do it either by hand (using FTP and manually creating the database) or automatically, using MT's installer. Your choice. The result is the same, meaning a clean Worpdress install.
4. Use import option in your new, MT-hosted Wordpress to recover your posts, pages, links, attachments e.t.c.

You should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you. Is the export.xml enough to get everything i need out of there?

Comment: It should be enough to transfer your posts, pages, categories and so on but I am not sure about non-textual data like images. I have not made an export from wordpress.com for a long time. There is also one more thing you need to be careful about - the URL structure. If, on wordpress.com, you put links to your posts in other posts, if the URL structure in your self-hosted installation is not the same as on wordpress.com, the links will point to nowhere, returning the 404 error. So you can either use the same URL structure or just correct the links.

Comment: It worked out fine. The images did show up. It didn't bring my theme. I have to go look it up to remember what i had. Since it didn't bring the theme my header image wasn't liked. However posts and such were fine. I used the same URL dansabin.com so i don't lose any links.